# C# program for odd even number

Tags: c#

Hi i am doing very basic c# coding where just checking odd and even number however how i can re-enter input while i am converting a string into integer at one place.

```
        if (i % 2==0) 

            {
            Console.WriteLine("even");
            Console.WriteLine("enter again", i);
        }
        else if(i%2!=0)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("odd");
            Console.WriteLine("enter again", i);
enter code here
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Console.Write("enter");
            i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: If you have more information to put in your question you should put it into the question and not into a comment.

Comment: You do not need to have that condition in else again since your "if" already checks for == 0 so only time it comes to else is when its != so checking that again is redundant. Unless there is something else which I'm missing.

Answer (score 3):

You want to do something like that ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var l = string.Empty;
        while (l != "exit")
        {
            l = Console.ReadLine();
            int i;
            if (!int.TryParse(l, out i)) continue;
            Console.WriteLine(i%2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd");
            Console.WriteLine("enter again");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Great but..why the `else if`? `i % 2` is 0 or not 0 :)

Comment: Also there's no need for passing `i` in `Console.WriteLine("enter again", i);` since there are no format items in the string.

Comment: Thx but I wanted to keep the closest code as the OP post (I edited my answer). Anyway juharr's answer is the best one

Comment: You probably should at least write out something when the user enters a non-integer value that isn't "exit".

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need a loop and you could make it stop when the user enters a non-integer value.

```
int i;
Console.WriteLine("enter a number");
while(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i%2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd");
    Console.WriteLine("enter again");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
{
    string userChoice,number;
    int checkInt;
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want check even/odd number?y/n");
    userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
    if (userChoice.ToLower().Equals("y"))
    {
        do
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your number");
            number = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(number, out checkInt))
            {
                if ((checkInt % 2) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your entered number {0} is even", checkInt);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your entered number {0} is odd", checkInt);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Plesae enter integer value");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Do you want check even/odd number?y/n");
            userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        } while (userChoice.ToLower().Equals("y"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need a loop that ask you to insert a new number until it is convertible into a integer number.

I suggest you this possible solution

```
    static int ReadInput(string message)
    {
        int n = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n));

        return n;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = ReadInput("Enter a Number");
        if (i % 2==0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("even");
        }
        else if(i%2!=0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("odd");
            //enter code here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert `String` into `int` for a even odd program, the following code can work out -

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        int i;
        Console.Write("Enter a Number : ");
        i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("Entered Number is an Even Number");
            Console.Read();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Entered Number is an Odd Number");
            Console.Read();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a really fast method:

```
If (rowNum % 2 == 0)
Print even row color info
```

Else
Print odd row color info